# направить с папки на файл (apache2, htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

Требуется, чтобы при переходе по url www.example.com/**test** выполнялся скрипт www.example.com/**test.php**

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как это можно сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^folder/?$ file.php [L]
```

Вот так =)